# How to extend laptop to multiple monitor in linux?

Tags: linux, display, multi-monitor, laptop

I have Asus ROG Strix G15 laptop running Pop_OS and 2 FHD monitors, i want to extend (not mirroring) the display to those 2 monitors. What can i do to make it like the following:

1. To make it so the laptop as 1st display and the 2 monitors as 2nd & 3rd display
2. To make it so the 2 monitors as 1st & 2nd display while the laptop lid is closed

How can i do that? is there a device that i should buy to make this possible?

Comment: You should have HDMI and USB C port that supports DisplayPort on your laptop. First, figure out the cabling. Will you connect one monitor to HDMI and other to USB C with USB C to DisplayPort cable? There are also adapters from USB C to two DisplayPorts, but you have to be careful, because they might not support the required resolution. After you have the cabling, you can configure displays as on every other computer with more displays. For option 2 you should first make sure, computer does not go to sleep when lid is closed.

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the answer, i also found out about adapter from USB-C to dual HDMI i think this is what i'm looking for,